# React render component inside a JSX argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a system for translations that returns a correct translation based on a key. And this is all handled by a component Translate:

```
import React from 'react';

const Translate = ({ ln }) => {

    return <span>{language[ln]}</span>
};

export default Translate;
```

the problem is that when I try to use it inside a for example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder=<Translate ln="text_input" /> />
```

The problem is that component has not returned - executed when I insert it into the `<input />`, that means that my placeholder will always be [object Object], is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass to `placeholder` React component, because to `placeholder` you should pass `String` not `Object` or `String` that [`contains tags`](https://jsfiddle.net/dvv064m7/)., I think in this case better split `Translate` to couple functions, and use it in `Translate` component and as just a function that returns right translation by key, like so

```
const translate = (key) => {
  // Some code ... 
  return language[ln];
}; // returns string

const Translate = ({ ln }) => {
  return <span>{ translate(ln) }</span>
}; // return React component

<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder={ translate('some key') } /> // pass string to placeholder
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a component for translating a string in the first place? I think this isn't good seperation of concerns and makes your translator less reusable.

Just use a function for that like

```
<input type="text" placeholder={t('text')} />
```

You could for example use something like [i18next](http://i18next.com/) for translation like

```
<input type="text" placeholder={i18next.t('text')} />
```